# How to find with lookahead in Visual studio 2012 Regex Find and Replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012, replace, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to find all using statements that are in cs files that contain a reference to a class *anywhere* in the file following it.

For example, I want to match `using Example.Foo;` if `BaseClass<SomeClass>` is found anywhere in the file following it.

Like such:

[image]

I've tried `(using Example.Foo;)(?=[.\s\n]*BaseClass\<SomeClass\>[.\s\n]*)` but no joy...

***UPDATE***

For clarity, this is for the VS 2012 IDE Find and Replace dialog.

Comment: try this pattern `(?s)(?=.*BaseClass<SomeClass>)using\sExample\.Foo;`

Comment: @491243, that didn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

```
(?s)using Example\.Foo;(?=(.*|\s\r)BaseClass\<SomeClass\>(.*|\s\r))
```

This does the trick!

Thanks for the `(?s)` hint, that was required! +1 for that...

Comment: You don't need to escape the angle brackets. They're not regular expression operators.

Comment: @Nashenas it looks like they are in Visual Studio. For example: `(?<pet>dog|cat)` finds dog or cat and replaces it with pet.

Comment: I forgot about named captures =/.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a (?s), which enables multiline matching, and also escape the period in `using Example.Foo`. The regex should be something along the lines of:

`(?s)using Example\.Foo;(?=.*BaseClass<SomeClass>)`

Comment: That didn't work, is this for the VS 2012 Find and Replace dialog (with RegEx enabled)?